# How do I build index for MySQL table that inserts a lot and queries only most recent data

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, index-tuning

I have a MySQL database table using InnoDB and looks like this:

```
OrgID (INTEGER)
MachID (INTEGER)
Date (DATETIME)
IdleTime (INTEGER)
```

I do two operations on this table:

1. Insert a new record, with Org ID, Mach ID, Date and IdleTime
2. Query for either a given Organization/Machine ID pair, for last day, the sum of IdleTime:

`SELECT SUM(IdleTime) FROM DBTable WHERE OrgID=1 AND MachID=2 AND Date BETWEEN 'YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00' AND 'YYYY-mm-dd 23:59:59';`

We may want to get the sum of total IdleTime for given OrgID, but it is just an extra bonus. In most cases, YYYY-mm-dd is *yesterday*.

We concern more on the performance of`INSERT` operation but we do not want too slow `SELECT`. My boss recommended adding a new column as the primary key, namely something like `INSERT_TIME(TIMESTAMP)` , to ensure insertion is sequential. I am wondering if using a `PRIMARY KEY (OrgID, MachID, Date)` may help. Any suggestions on how do I use the index to boost the performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PRIMARY KEY (OrgID, MachID, Date)` would be good for that query.  *But*, a `PRIMARY KEY` is necessarily "unique"; is that combination unique?  If not unique, then make it a plain `INDEX` and have something else as the `PRIMARY KEY`.

If we are talking about millions of rows per day, then Summary tables would be worth doing.

If it is usually "yesterday", then consider:

```
AND Date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND Date  < CURDATE()
```

Or, more generically, (where you insert the days ago for '?'):

```
AND Date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL ?   DAY
AND Date  < CURDATE() - INTERVAL ?-1 DAY
```

**More**

Insuring sequential -- not that important.  With that 3-part PK, you will be inserting sequentially in several spots, namely each combination of `OrgID` and `MachID`.

`Insert` do need to update secondary keys, but this is usually not a big deal.  (To get really technical, see "InnoDB's change buffering".)

If you are going to be inserting more than 100 rows per *second*, then I recommend gathering them up and batch inserting.  Also, see `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2`.

Comment: AFAIK OrgID, MachID and Date combination is `UNIQUE` base on our current situation: each machine report the idleness hourly to the database. Also can you give me some reference on this: "With that 3-part PK, you will be inserting sequentially in several spots, namely each combination of OrgID and MachID."?

Comment: Assuming you are using `ENGINE=InnoDB`, then the index is a "BTree" where the ordering is those 3 columns.  Read about BTrees in Wikipedia.

Comment: It sounds like writes will all be for today (or yesterday) and reads will typically be filtering using date, in which case the order `PRIMARY KEY (Date, OrgID, MachID)` would probably give better results. This allows you to read and write sequentially.

Comment: `(Date, ...)` leads to filtering out rows not of interest.  `(..., Date)` will touch _only_ the necessary row; it is _more efficient_ (given that you are testing OrgID and MachID with '=').

Answer (score 0):

INNODB uses a compound pkey, meaning the pkey IS the table. Having no pkey at all, as in the first example, makes innodb produce a fake internal pkey, so it is able to store the data at all.

So it is always better to have an explicit pkey for innodb. If the pkey from the second example works: use it!